# End of theorem marker placement

Tags: theorems

I have a question about marker placement after theorems. I am using a style file provided by Oxford University Press, which I am not used to. It is available here:

http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/imrn/for_authors/tex_template.zip

This style file wants to put an `\openbox` at the end of the statement of each theorem, and a `\filledbox` at the end of every proof.

If one concludes a proof with an equation, I know to use `\qedhere` to position the end of proof marker correctly. But I don't know how to do something similar in the above situation (after the statement of a theorem). Many of the thoerems, propositions etc. end with equations, and if I use the above style sheet the box is placed too low.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try using the `\qedhere` command? If so, what are the results?

Comment: (Also, if you are submitting to IMRN, why not just let the publisher/copyeditor worry about it?)

Comment: I tried using \qedhere, but it puts a black box, rather than a white box, at the desired spot! You are right that I should just let the publisher deal with it, but it is really annoying me (and makes the document more difficult to read).

Comment: I should also mention that when I use \qedhere the white box is _replaced_ by the black box, so it is almost the right thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine `\qedsymbol` just before using `\qedhere` as in:

```
\begin{proposition}
This is a funny equation
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c\,. \let\qedsymbol\openbox\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proposition}
```

I don't know if it is possible, but you could maybe also suggest the people from the journal to fix their class file so that `\qedhere` works as expected?

Comment: thanks ... this works very nicely. Willie Wong's suggestion below also works, but the alignment is better with the above option. (That is, it is right aligned as it should be, not just next to the final equation etc.)

Comment: this is all very well, but it only works if equation numbers are on the right side of the page.  the ams document class default is for equation numbers on the left, so simply dropping the qed box into the equation number position doesn't work.  that's why the definition of \qedhere in amsthm is so complicated.  more comments on other answers.

Comment: @barbara, thanks for your comment! I've checked the link you posted below and indeed it looks very useful. If you could craft a short new answer pointing to the link and with a small example that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: in the math environment, put the `\qedhere` command inside of an `\mbox`, as in

```
\[ .... some numbers and equation. \mbox{\qedhere} \]
```

it won't work completely correctly, but now the mark inserted is the openbox, and not the filled box. I think this is a bug with `amsthm` (see below the cut), so you'd be best off just leaving well-enough alone and let the journal deal with it later.

---

The `oupau` class apparently uses `amsthm` and not `ntheorem` for its theorem needs. And this is how it defines the open-box symbol for the QED in the theorem environment:

```
\providecommand{\qedsymbolthm}{\openbox}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qedthm}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbolthm}%
  \fi
}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \pushQED{\qedthm}\deferred@thm@head{\the\thm@headfont \thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct
    \thmheadnl % possibly a newline.
    \hskip\thm@headsep
  }%
  \ignorespaces}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
```

I don't think the problem is actually with Oxford University Press! I think the problem lies in `amsthm`! See the definition there for `\qedhere`

```
\newcommand{\qedhere}{%
  \begingroup \let\mathqed\math@qedhere
    \let\qed@elt\setQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax \endgroup
}
```

and the definition for the proof environment

```
\providecommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox}%
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

I'm thinking that the `pushQED` and `popQED` commands are defined just so they can accomodate different end symbols! The problem, apparently, lies in the definition of `\qedhere`, which calls `\math@qedhere` when it sits in a math environment. And unfortunately, instead of the definitions used in `\setQED@elt` (which is called in text mode), which process the current qed symbol that's in the QED stack, `\math@qedhere` depends on

```
\newcommand{\mathqed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}
\def\linebox@qed{\hfil\hbox{\qedsymbol}\hfilneg}
```

which explictly references the `\qedsymbol`, which is defined to be the filled box in `oupau.cls`. So in short, **the `amsthm` package, uses two different ways of accessing the QED symbol depending on whether the environment ends naturally (with `\popQED`) or if you insert the symbol using `\qedhere` inside a math environment**. This, I think, is a bug.

Comment: It is a bit hard to say what should the “correct” behavior of internal (not documented) macros of `amsthm`. In their definitions `\qedsymbol` is used all over the place, not just in the definition of `\qed` so I'm not sure if they really intended the push/pop pair of commands to accomodate for different symbols.

Comment: ...which is why I'm glad you took a look also. I agree it is hard to figure out what the "intent" is. I am a bit surprised that OUP opted for hacking `amsthm` instead of `ntheorem`, which, IIRC, already has the same sets of defaults (open box for thms and filled box for proofs), and works better.

Comment: the documentation of the qed handling in amsthm is sketchy, but not entirely absent.  see amsclass.pdf -- the source from which amsthm.sty was generated (amsclass.dtx) is identified at the top of that file.  i have added a request to our "open" list to improve this documentation.

Comment: it was not originally recognized that "boxes" would be wanted at the end of anything other than proofs, but over the past year there have been numerous requests for this facility.  a wholesale upgrade of this feature, including adding the ability to mark non-proofs, is on our to-do list.  in the meantime, see this entry in the ams author faq: http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=212 . it contains a link to an example file that demonstrates various tactics that can be used with amsthm to get different symbols and put them in different locations.

Comment: @barbara: thank you so much for your pointers! I haven't played with the linked tex file yet, but it looks like it will help quite a bit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I've played with the linked tex file; nothing from there produced a correctly spaced qed box (inside an equation at the end of a lemma). Suggestions?

Comment: A bit more detail - the theorem environment appears to eat qed boxes inside of equation environments, _except_ for the one wrapped in the command \xqedhere.  But I don't want to adjust the spacing by hand... :(

Comment: @SamNead -- sadly, although there have been many requests to make it available also within theorem-class environments, the basic `\qedhere` works only in the `proof` environment.  (this was a design decision.)  it is likely that it will be extended, but certainly not for many months (the upgrade has been delayed many times for other priorities, and may be delayed again).  until then, adjusting the spacing by hand is the only alternative i know of, and i've tried *many* things.

Comment: @WillieWong -- you wonder why oxford started with `amsthm` instead of `ntheorem`.  if you look at the sources, you can see that work on `ntheorem` didn't begin until 1997.  `amsthm` was built on the foundation of ams-tex, which was created in the early 1980s, and the earliest `amsthm` dates from before 1990, although the version for latex2e didn't emerge until 1995.  in `oupau.cls`, it says "based on the original LaTeX ARTICLE DOCUMENT STYLE. Copyright (C) 1988, 1989 by Leslie Lamport", so oxford started work on their classes quite early, probably pre-`ntheorem`.

Comment: @barbara: wow. I have to admit (rather shamefully) that "because `ntheorem` didn't exists" never crossed  my mind as a possible answer; but now that you pointed it out, it seems so very natural.