# Determining the math class of a non-keyboard symbol

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, mathcode

What is the "right" way of determining the math class (e.g. ordinary/0, relation/3, closing/5, etc.) of a non-keyboard symbol?

Something like `\oplus` is easy enough to guess, but I wasn't immediately sure about `\upuparrows` ([image]); on the one hand, my impression is that arrow symbols are generally treated as relations, while I know that [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation) uses it to denote a binary operation.

I tried writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\the\mathcode\upuparrows
\end{document}
```

but this produced an error:

```
Bad character code (13332) \the\mathcode\upuparrows
```

Note that `13332` *is the right number*: writing

```
\def\test{\mathchar 13332 }
$\test$
```

does not produce an error, and gives the double-up-arrow symbol. And `13332` is equal to the hex number `3414`, which starts with 3, correctly indicating that it is a relation.

How did I end up figuring out that is correct? Because I ran the following extremely silly code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\test}
\setbox0=\hbox{$a\mathord{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox1=\hbox{$a\mathop{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox2=\hbox{$a\mathbin{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox3=\hbox{$a\mathrel{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox4=\hbox{$a\mathopen{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox5=\hbox{$a\mathclose{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox6=\hbox{$a\mathpunct{\upuparrows}b$}
\setbox7=\hbox{$a\upuparrows b$}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
mathord    &  \setlength{\test}{\wd0}  \the\test\\
mathop     &  \setlength{\test}{\wd1}  \the\test\\
mathbin    &  \setlength{\test}{\wd2}  \the\test\\
mathrel    &  \setlength{\test}{\wd3}  \the\test\\
mathopen   &  \setlength{\test}{\wd4}  \the\test\\
mathclose  &  \setlength{\test}{\wd5}  \the\test\\
mathpunct  &  \setlength{\test}{\wd6}  \the\test\\[0.1in]
ACTUAL     &  \setlength{\test}{\wd7}  \the\test\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

Obviously this is not the right way of going about it either; besides the silliness, there is the issue that several math classes can have the same length.

Now in contrast, writing `` \the\mathcode`< `` worked fine; it produced `12604` (which is `313C` in hexadecimal, which has leading digit 3 = mathrel, as it should).

I did try adding the backtick in front of `\upuparrows`, but this just produced the errors

```
Improper alphabetic constant \the\mathcode`\upuparrows
Missing $ inserted \the\mathcode`\upuparrows
Missing $ inserted
```

*(Incidentally, what is the backtick doing exactly? I am reading the TeXbook and the examples given there use it, e.g. [image] but I couldn't find an explanation.)*

I also tried the approach that seemed to be suggested by [this TeX.SE thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109440/27533):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\the\mathcode\string\upuparrows
\end{document}
```

but that produced

```
Missing number, treated as zero \the\mathcode\string\upuparrows
```

Comment: The backquote denotes an "alphabetical constant": `\`b ` when TeX is looking for a number denotes the position of `b` in the ASCII code. It can be used only in front of a character or a (not necessarily defined) control sequence whose name consists of *one* character. Thus ``\the\mathcode`\\`` is legal although not very useful because it gives the mathcode of the backslash. Only characters have a mathcode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\show\upuparrows` instead. You will get this response:

```
> \upuparrows=\mathchar"3414.
```

Now you need to decode that. As explained in section 21.1 of TeX by Topic, that code is parsed as `"xyzz` where `x` is the math class, answering your question right there – while `y` is the font family number and `zz` is the position of the character in the font.

To add a little detail, `\mathchar` is a command to typeset the given character with the given class and family. And as you might guess, that is how non-keyboard characters are handled. Only actual characters have an associated `\mathcode`.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than showing each command separately you can get TeX to show you the current math list structure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$ a \sin b \upuparrows \times 2   \showoutput \showlists $

\end{document}
```

Produces, on the terminal and log:

```
### math mode entered at line 5
\mathord
.\fam1 a
\mathop\nolimits
.\mathord
..\fam0 s
.\mathord
..\fam0 i
.\mathord
..\fam0 n
\mathord
.\fam1 b
\mathrel
.\fam4 ^^T
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^B
\mathord
.\fam0 2
```

which tells you in that expression `\upuparrows` produced a mathrel atom followed by the mathbin from `\times`.