# "^^A" does not work in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, characters, ascii

On page 45 of **The TeXbook**,

> TEX has a standard way to refer to the invisible characters of ASCII: Code 0 can be typed as the sequence of three characters `^^@`, code 1 can be typed `^^A`, and so on up to code 31, which is `^^_` (see Appendix C).

The `^^@`, `^^B` and `^^C` and so on all works but `^^A` doesn't.

```
^^@\par
^^B\par
^^C\par
^^D\par
\bye
```

produces

[image]

but `^^A` causes an error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   ^^A
l.5 ^^A
```

Why can't use `^^A` in TeX?

Comment: The input method does not change the catcode. So if you use the ^^ syntax to input a character, that will result in a math token, it still requires the math mode. This is the case with `^^A` but neither with `^^@` not `^^B`, `^^C` or `^^D`.

Comment: @cabohah `$^^A$` fails too.

Comment: But with another error message. Try for example `$x^^A{y}$`. (Note: In plainTeX (not in LaTeX) `^^A` has catcode 8 and therefore is a math subscript.)

Comment: @cabohah How do you know it has catcode 8?

Comment: You can find it in `plain.tex` line 17 or ask TeX using ``\showthe\catcode`\^^A``.

Comment: @cabohah how does that then match with this from `plain.tex`: `\mathcode`\^^A="3223 % \downarrow` or is `\downarrow` in plain TeX just the same as `_`?

Comment: Please read, how `\mathcode` works.

Answer (score 10):

The error message you get, indicates that `^^A` results in a math token. In `plain.TeX` you can find:

```latex
\catcode`\_=8 \catcode`\^^A=8 % underline and downarrow are for subscripts
```

(Note: This part of `plain.tex` can also be found in Appendix B of “The TeXbook”, page 343.)

From this point `^^A` is a math subscript. This corresponds with the terminal output of

```latex
\showthe\catcode`\^^A
\bye
```

> ```
> 8.
> l.1 \showthe\catcode`\^^A
> ```

Note: The later

```latex
\mathcode`\^^A="3223 % \downarrow
```

in `plain.tex` is irrelevant for the catcode of `^^A`. And because the catcode of `^^A` is neither 11 (letter) nor 12 (other) the mathcode is also not relevant for the output. But it can become relevant, e.g., after changing the catcode of `^^A`:

```latex
$x^^A{y}$

\catcode`\^^A=12 $x^^A{y}$
\bye
```

[image]

For more information about `\mathcode`, how it works and the difference to `\catcode` see “The TeXbook” and “[What is the differences between mathcode and catcode and how can I use mathcode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109436/277964)”

Comment: If I remember correctly my TeXbook, the ascii code 1 was rendered as ↓ in some terminal DEK used at the time (and the same for the uparrow at `^^K`)

Comment: Thanks. How can I see the code in `plain.tex` as I don't know where it is?

Comment: @Y.zeng `kpsewhich plain.tex` and then search for `^^A` in that file. Or because you are reading The TeXbook, have a look into Appendix B. But as I have also shown, you can alternatively ask TeX for the catcode.

Answer (score 7):

You can *refer* to invisible ASCII characters, but the TeXbook doesn't say you can, or should, use them just for fun.

For instance, `^^@` (the null byte) has category code 9, so

```
Hell^^@ w^^@rld
```

would result in “Hell wrld”. And indeed you obtain ***three*** characters in output and not four.

To the contrary, `^^A` (the 1 byte), has category code 8. Here's the table of category codes as set up in plain TeX:

[image]

Why the choice for `^^@`? Because some operating systems used the null byte in order to fill their fixed length records. There should be no surprise in seeing category code 5 assigned to `^^M`. Two cases remain, namely `^^A` and `^^K`.

The keyboard which Knuth used to work with could produce `↓` and `↑` when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, respectively, and he liked these visual hints more than `^` and `_`. A consequence of this is that

```
$x^^A0$
```

has the same effect as `$x_0$`. And, of course, `$^^A$` raises an error, because it would be like `$_$`.

You find the symbols on Knuth's keyboard in the table on page 369. This table also explains why some of these bytes are assigned a mathcode.

For instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> would produce `∧` on Knuth's screen and indeed we find

```
\mathcode`\^^D="225E % \land
```

in `plain.tex`.

Just for completeness, you can use `^^00` instead of `^^@`. This convention is also described in chapter 8 and was added in TeX version 3.

Comment: Thanks. 1. Why did you say "And indeed you obtain three characters in output and not four.", witch are 8 characters? 2. Why does `hello1 ^^M hello2 \bye` output `hello1`? 3. Does `^^` always find symbols from ASCII?

Comment: @Y.zeng Look at the output: you get Theta, Lambda and Xi, which are the characters in slots 1, 2 and 3 in `cmr10`, but nothing for character 0 (which has a Gamma, by the way). For the second question, reread chapter 7: upon finding a character with catcode 5, TeX discards it and everything that may remain on the current line and replaces it with the `\endlinechar`. Question 3: what do you mean?

Comment: 1. What is **Theta**, **Lambda**, **Xi** and **Gamma** here? What I get is **Hell wrld**. 3. For example, in `^^t`, `t` is 116th symbol of ASCII. As 116 is bigger than 64, 116-64=52.  In ASCII table, 52th symbol is `4`, so `^^t` ouputs `4`. Doesn't this state that `^^` always outputs symbols from ASCII?

Comment: @Y.zeng You've already read, that `\char 127` after switching to font `manfnt` results in a symbol different from ASCII and that the same can be done using `^^?` after setting up catcode of `^^?` and the font. And I've already shown, that `^^A` can result in output of a down arrow or a math subscript. So you should already know, that `^^` does not always output a symbol from ASCII. As already explained, `^^` is an *input method*. The output is more or less independent from the input, because the input can also result in, e.g., active character tokens.

Answer (score 5):

Because on an old computer system with old keyboards that Don Knuth used, the character set had a down-arrow as character 1 (^^A). That seemed like a useful synonym for the underscore as math subscript character, so it has catcode 8.
Likewise for an up-arrow character at location 11 given catcode 7 like ^.
The character set is shown in Appendix C.

Comment: From Appendix C, `^` is 136 and `_` is 137, from witch how to know it is the up-arrow key and down-arrow key?

Comment: That character set is the third table in Appendix C, on page 369 in my book.