# QED symbol in a custom theorem environment

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I have created my own theorem environment like this

```
\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}{}{}{}{}{\scshape}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle} \newtheorem{mythm}{Theorem}
```

How do I add the QED symbol (the white rectangle) into this custom environment? The \qedhere should work for it too, in case I need it.

Comment: "QED" is added to proof, not to theorem.

Comment: please see my answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12827/insert-a-symbol-at-the-end-of-line); it contains pointers to references for placing the qed symbol in places other than at the end of a proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use the [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\scshape,
  notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=1em,
  qed=\qedsymbol
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
test
\[
a\qedhere
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using the `amsthm` package, you could simply redefine the package's `\@endtheorem` macro to include the `\qed` instruction, which will place an empty square box at the far right end of the theorem's last line. It's necessary to surround such a redefinition with a pair of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instructions because the `@` symbol is (deliberately) special in LaTeX. The following MWE shows how this may be achieved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% redefine the \@endtheorem macro
\makeatletter  
\def\@endtheorem{\qed\endtrivlist\@endpefalse } % insert `\qed` macro
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}{}{}{}{}{\scshape}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle} 
\newtheorem{mythm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{mythm}[Pythagoras]
Consider a right triangle with sides of length $a$, $b$, and 
$c$, and assume w.l.o.g.\ that $a\le b<c$. Then $a^2+b^2=c^2$. 
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this approach, though simple, isn't quite perfect because the qed symbol won't be placed correctly if the theorem *ends* with a displayed equation. In such cases, you should probably follow the approach provided in Gonzalo's answer, which employs the powerful `thmtools` package.

Comment: Will your solution affect all theorem like environments? How to do this only for one kind (`example` for example, not for the others `theorem`, `corollary`, etc...)

Comment: @Sigur - To limit the scope of the proposed solution to a specific theorem style (e.g., `mythmstyle`), be sure to define all other theorem-like environments of your document *before* redefining `\@endtheorem` and setting up any new theorem styles and associated theorem-like environments (e.g., `mythm`).

Comment: @Mico Can you also show how to redefine the qed sign locally for this specific theorem style? Doing `\renewcommand\qedsymbol{something}` makes changes globally. But grouping it inside `\@endtheorem`, `\def\@endtheorem{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{something}\qed\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}` seems to work fine. Do you recommend this approach?