# How can I apply a custom-defined theorem environment to nested theorems WITHOUT using a proof environment?

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm, nesting, proof-package

I'd like to combine a couple of constructions I've found on this site to create a custom-defined `cases` environment so that each case will:

1. be nested within a larger `theorem` environment;
2. end with a `qedsymbol` **without** needing a `proof` environment; and
3. use a custom `qedsymbol` consisting of the boxed case name.

That sounds like a lot, so let me make this more precise.

I'd like the general form of my document to be as shown in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{underline}% name
{-1.5mm}        % Space above, empty = `usual value'
{}              % Space below
{}              % Body font
{\parindent}    % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{}              % Thm head font
{:}             % Punctuation after thm head
{1.5mm}         % Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
{{\underline{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}~\thmnote{(#3)}}}}  % Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{underline}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}

\begin{document}
   \begin{thm} 
      Here is a theorem.
   \end{thm}
   \begin{proof} 
      Consider the following two cases:
         \begin{case} 
            Case 1 is...
         \end{case}
         \begin{case} 
            Case 2 is...
         \end{case}
      As the preceding cases show, we've proven something!
   \end{proof}    
\end{document}
```

As written, that renders as follows:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to enhance this MWE by combining two separate SxE posts, namely:

- Using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48878/qed-symbol-in-a-custom-theorem-environment), I want to end each instance of `case` with a `qedsymbol` **without** requiring the addition of `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}`; and
- using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203235/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-defined-theorem-environment-to-nested-theorems-only), I want to recognize that `case` is nested and to change the `qedsymbol` mentioned previously to be boxed versions of `Case 1`, `Case 2`, etc.

The desired end result would render something like this:

[image]

. For the record, the solution of the first linked question has the form

```
% redefine the \@endtheorem macro
\makeatletter  
\def\@endtheorem{\qed\endtrivlist\@endpefalse } % insert `\qed` macro
\makeatother
```

(note that I'm trying to use the `amsthm` solution), and the solution of the second linked question has the form

```
\makeatletter
\let\qed@empty\openbox % <--- change here, if desired
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \deferred@thm@head{%
    \the\thm@headfont\thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}
      {\let\thmname\@gobble}
      {\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}
      {\let\thmnumber\@gobble\global\let\qed@current\qed@empty}
      {\let\thmnumber\@iden\xdef\qed@current{#2}}%
    \@ifempty{#3}
      {\let\thmnote\@gobble}
      {\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead
    \thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct\thmheadnl\hskip\thm@headsep
  }\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
    \qed@empty
  \else
    \fbox{\scriptsize\qed@thiscurrent}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{%
  Proof%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
  \else
    \ of \qed@thiscurrent
  \fi
}
\xpretocmd{\proof}{\let\qed@thiscurrent\qed@current}{}{}
\newenvironment{proof*}[1]
  {\def\qed@thiscurrent{\ref{#1}}\proof}
  {\endproof}
\makeatother
```

(requiring only `amsthm` and `xpatch`).

Is this possible?

Comment: It certainly is simpler to do with `ntheorem`.

Comment: @Bernard - You're surely correct. However, this particular implementation will likely end up in my dissertation and my university's dissertation class conflicts infamously with a number of excellent packages. To avoid a potential conflict, I'd prefer solutions with fewer potential conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. We need

```
\let\mtendcase\endcase
\renewcommand{\endcase}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\tiny\fbox{case \thecase}}\qed\mtendcase}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\newtheoremstyle{underline}% name
{-1.5mm}        % Space above, empty = `usual value'
{}              % Space below
{}              % Body font
{\parindent}    % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{}              % Thm head font
{:}             % Punctuation after thm head
{1.5mm}         % Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
{{\underline{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}~\thmnote{(#3)}}}}  % Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{underline}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\let\mtendcase\endcase
\renewcommand{\endcase}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\tiny\fbox{case \thecase}}\qed\mtendcase}

\begin{document}
   \begin{thm} 
      Here is a theorem.
   \end{thm}
   \begin{proof} 
      Consider the following two cases:
         \begin{case} 
            Case 1 is...
         \end{case}
         \begin{case} 
            Case 2 is...
         \end{case}
      As the preceding cases show, we've proven something!
   \end{proof}    
\end{document}
```

[image]