# A custom theorem-like environment without \qed at the end (with the journal class file)

Tags: environments, theorems

Inspired by the style of old French papers, see for instance [Borel et Tits, Groupes réductifs](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1965__27__55_0), I use in my papers my custom theorem-like environment `subsec`:

`\newtheorem{subsec}[equation]{}`

It works fine with the `amsart` class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
   \numberwithin{equation}{section}
   \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}   
\theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{rem}[equation]{Remark}
      \newtheorem{subsec}[equation]{}
\begin{document}
\section{Motivation} \label{s:motivation}
   \begin{subsec}\label{ss:mod-Y}
       Throughout the article, $k_0$ is a field of characteristic $0$,
       and  $k$ is  a fixed algebraic closure of $k_0$.
   \end{subsec}
   \begin{rem}
      We use the term ``$k_0$-model'' rather than ``$k_0$-form''
      because the term ``form'' is overloaded.
   \end{rem}
   \begin{thm}
      For any two  numbers $x,y\in{\mathbb R}$, we have
      \begin{equation} x+y=y+x.\end{equation}
   \end{thm}
   \begin{proof} This is well known. \end{proof}
   \begin{subsec}      A $k_0$-torus $T_0$ is called {\em split} 
      if it is isomorphic to $({\mathbb G}_{m,k_0})^n$
      for some natural number $n$, where ${\mathbb G}_{m,k_0}$
      is the multiplicative group over $k_0$.
   \end{subsec}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Now my paper has been accepted for publication in the International Mathematics Research Notices (IMRN), and I must prepare it with the journal class file `oupau.cls`. This class file can be downloaded from the journal webpage (click Tex template).See below the corresponding file, for which the only essential difference with the previous file is the first line `\documentclass{oupau}` instead of  `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}` :

`````
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
   \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
      \newtheorem{rem}[equation]{Remark}
      \newtheorem{subsec}[equation]{}
\begin{document}
\section{Motivation} \label{s:motivation}
   \begin{subsec}\label{ss:mod-Y}
      Throughout the article, $k_0$ is a field of characteristic $0$,
      and  $k$ is  a fixed algebraic closure of $k_0$.
   \end{subsec}
   \begin{rem}
      We use the term ``$k_0$-model'' rather than ``$k_0$-form''
      because the term ``form'' is overloaded.
   \end{rem}
   \begin{thm}
      For any two  numbers $x,y\in{\mathbb R}$, we have
      \begin{equation} x+y=y+x.\end{equation}
   \end{thm}
   \begin{proof} This is well known. \end{proof}
   \begin{subsec}
      A $k_0$-torus $T_0$ is called {\em split} 
     if it is isomorphic to $({\mathbb G}_{m,k_0})^n$
     for some natural number $n$, where ${\mathbb G}_{m,k_0}$
      is the multiplicative group over $k_0$.   \end{subsec}
\end{document}``` 

See the result at the end of my question (I could not put it here...)

As you can see, the ```oupau```` class puts a *solid square* at the end of the proof, 
and it puts an *empty square* ```\qed``` 
at the end of each theorem-like environment. 

In particular, each time when I write ```\end{subsec}``` 
I get a ```\qed``` symbol, which I don't need!

> **Request.**  Please write for me a theorem-like environment  ```subsec```
that will not put a ```\qed```-symbol when I write ```\end{subsec}```.

See below the relevant part (?) of the ```oupau``` class file.
`````

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qedthm}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbolthm}%
  \fi
}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \pushQED{\qedthm}\deferred@thm@head{\the\thm@headfont \thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct
    \thmheadnl % possibly a newline.
    \hskip\thm@headsep
  }%
  \ignorespaces}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
%
\newcommand{\filledbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em height.6em}\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\filledbox}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par\noindent
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \textbf
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
```

Feel free to add/edit tags, and please kindly format my question correctly!
[image]

Comment: It may be easier to just define a separate environment for `subsec` that doesn't piggy back on theorem. Are your `subsec`s ever named? (I mean do you ever type `\begin{subsec}[Important Paragraph] ... \end{subsec}`?)

Comment: @WillieWong: No, my ```subsec```s  are *never* named.

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes, this is what I need: to define a separate environment for ```subsec```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the definition of `subsec` using `\newtheorem` with the following

```
\newenvironment{subsec}{%
\noindent\refstepcounter{equation}{\normalfont\bfseries\theequation.}\hspace{0.5em}}{}
```

The `\hspace` probably will need to be adjusted, I don't know what the spacing between the theorem head and the body is in the theorem environments in `oupau.cls`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I  have adjusted ```\hspace{0.5em}``` to ```\hspace{0.35em}``` and added ```\medskip``` before ```noindent```.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer to my question (using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48886/79552)  to a related question,  and [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48878/qed-symbol-in-a-custom-theorem-environment?rq=1#comment398164_48886)).
The idea is to redefine the `\@endtheorem` macro by deleting `\qed`.

```
% redefine the \@endtheorem macro
\makeatletter
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist\@endpefalse } % delete `\qed` macro
\makeatother
%
\newtheoremstyle{subsecthmstyle}{}{}{}{}{\bf}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{subsecthmstyle}
\newtheorem{subsec}[equation]{}
```