# How to insert a symbol to left of a line

Tags: symbols, lineno

I'm trying to find a solution to be able to insert a symbol (asterisk) at the beginning of the line of text without altering its length, that is, as for the line numbers with the lineno package, without the symbol being part of the text but on margin.

I found these threads but they were not helpful.
[Insert a symbol at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12827/insert-a-symbol-at-the-end-of-line)
I mean, I don't know how to insert the symbol on the left.
In the case of the previous discussion, the symbol at the end of the line still remains within the body of the text. Is it possible to have it externally (right or left)?

A minimal example with the symbol on the right using the discussion mentioned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\hfill\(*\) \\ Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
\end{document}
```

Thanks for all the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Some like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\marginpar{*} Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida

\reversemarginpar

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\marginpar{\hfill*} Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida


\end{document}
```

See also the package `marginnote`.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks @Fran! This solution works perfectly. Annie

Comment: @Annie  You are welcome. Please upvote  (clic on triangle above the number on the left) if you find the answer useful in some way, and accept it (click on the gray checkmark below) if completely solve your problem  (and is your preferred solution if there are more than one).

Comment: Hi Fran, also on other occasions when I voted for a reply the system did not show my +1. I don't know why, but your answer is certainly excellent and so I immediately commented.