# Overfull \hbox produced by ntheorem subtitles

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, warnings

I switched from using the standard AMS theorem package to `ntheorem` so I can put alternative end marks on theorem environments (I want my examples to have an end mark, but not the same one as proofs).  However, this seems to be causing another problem.

Many of my examples have subtitles, by which I mean I start them with
`\begin{example}[subtitle]`, 
where the subtitle is some description of the example.  Some of these subtitles are long enough that they need multiple lines, which works fine with the standard AMS environment.  On the other hand ntheorem seems to try to set the subtitle all on one line, giving an overfull `\hbox` whenever it is long enough that it should span multiple lines (I'm not talking a character or two wider than it knows how to deal with like a usual overfull `\hbox`, I mean they go through the whole margin and off the page).

This can be reproduced by

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,amsthm,thref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}[blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah]
Content
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in `ntheorem` or am I doing something wrong?  Perhaps this is an abuse of the subtitle field.  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: the ability to attach a symbol to the end of some object other than a proof is being requested more and more frequently, and is on the ams list of things to be considered in the next upgrade of amsthm.  in the meantime, take a look at [ams.org/faq?faq_id=212](http://ams.org/faq?faq_id=212) and at my comments on a couple of the answers to [this question about `qedhere`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/end-of-theorem-marker-placement) for suggested workarounds.

Comment: @barbara beeton: Thank you.  I didn't see those when I searched earlier because I thought the problem was specific to `ntheorem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; it's not a bug, although it could be considered a bad design choice; `ntheorem` uses the optional argument of `\item` to typeset the theorem header (name, number and annotation), and that causes the problem (I guess that the package author thought that an annotation shouldn't be too long). You can define your own style, imitating the existing `plain` style but modifying the undesired behaviour, so that you can now have annotations spanning several lines; the definition would be something along these lines, I used a checkmark (`\Checkmark` from `bbding`) as the endmark:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,amsthm,thref]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{Myplain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2]\theorem@headerfont (##3)\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont\itshape}
\newtheoremstyle{nonumberMyplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1]\theorem@headerfont (##3)\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont\itshape}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{Myplain}
\theoremsymbol{\Checkmark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}[blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah]
Content
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use the [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package which doesn't use `\item` to build its theorem-like structures, thus providing an easier solution (the same checkmark was used in this example):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{bbding}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries\bfseries,
  qed=\Checkmark,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{Example}


\begin{document}
\begin{Example}[blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah]
Content
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe one could call it a bug then that `\item` is used ...

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, maybe ntheorem's use of \item is not the best choice. I'll add another solution using the thmtools package which doesn't use \item

Comment: Well, `thmtools` uses whatever its backend uses, so if you use it in combination with `ntheorem` you'd have the same problem.

Comment: @Ulrich: yes, I know that, but using `thmtools` with `amsthm` you can have theorem-like structures with annotations spanning several lines (without long redefinitions) and the ability of setting endmarks.

Comment: `amsthm` was originally based on `\item` but there were so many complaints about long optional heading comments not breaking that it was thoroughly revised with the december 1999 upgrade to scrap that approach.  you might suggest to the author of `ntheorem` that a similar revision would be appreciated. (`proof` has the same problem, and it's on the ams list of things to be looked at with the next upgrade. the `list` environment is simply too restrictive in many ways, this being one of the most annoying.)

Comment: @barbara beeton: yes, I am thinking about making a request to the author of `ntheorem` in this regard.

Comment: Thank you.  My thesis looks much nicer now!  It seems that thmtools fits my needs better than ntheorem.