# Problem with solution to ntheorem and bad boxes; involves \newtheoremstyle

Tags: math-mode, theorems, ntheorem

I'm using the `ntheorem` package to display endmarks on my examples/defns, etc. The problem is that it creates lots of bad boxes when the titles on theorems etc. are too long. I found a solution [overfull-hbox-produced-by-ntheorem-subtitles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/overfull-hbox-produced-by-ntheorem-subtitles), which is to define the following in the preamble bit:

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{Myplain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2]\theorem@headerfont (##3)\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont\itshape}
\newtheoremstyle{nonumberMyplain}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1]\theorem@headerfont (##3)\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{Myplain}
\theoremsymbol{$\bigcirc$}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

And I use it with:

```
\begin{defn}[Definition of function]This is a definition of $f(x) = p_i(x^2)$.
\end{defn}
```

in my document to get this:

[image]

I don't want the math stuff to be in bold and italics. If I remove the label/title of the definition (Definition of function), the problem's solved. How do I change it so it looks normal even with a label? I know I have to mess around with the stuff after the `\makeatletter` but I don't understand it. Someone help please :(

Comment: Is there some reason not to switch to using `amsthm` and `thmtools` (as the accepted answer in your link suggests) to change the endmark display?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately those two have endmarks (for non-proof environments) that work poorly when you finish with a displayed equation.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the declaration `\boldmath` is in force when the optional argument is typeset (this might depend on settings in ntheorem). Solution:

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{Myplain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]\normalfont}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2]{\theorem@headerfont (##3)}\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont}
\newtheoremstyle{nonumberMyplain}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]\normalfont}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1]{\theorem@headerfont (##3)}\theorem@separator\newline\normalfont}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks once again. I changed the `\itshape` to `\upshape` and it got rid of the italics in the text for defns. with labels. It had no effect for definitions without labels -- still italics (but the math stuff is fine), but if I add `\normaltext` to each such definition it looks fine. Thank you again.

Comment: @P.A. Look at the changes in the proposed solution, that will give upright text in the environment's body.

Comment: the reason for the `\boldmath` is that ntheorem has a `\theorem@checkbold` macro which automatically switches `\boldmath` on when bold is used.