# placement of QED symbol on numbered equation line

Tags: equations, theorems

This question is both on LaTeX and on mathematics writing style; I hope that's still apropriate here.

I have a proof that ends with a (right) numbered equation, and I'm pondering about where to put the QED symbol. The standard right margin position conflicts with the equation number, so what would be considered best style for the QED placement?

Secondly, I use the ntheorem package, but cannot place the QED symbol using `\qedhere` on this equation line. Is there a (simple) way to solve this?

Comment: If equation numbers are on the right, I'd suggest never ending a proof with an equation as there's no sensible placement for the QED symbol.

Comment: Have you checked out the question "End of theorem marker placement" (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/end-of-theorem-marker-placement) and the answers that were provided? Also, have you tried loading the `ntheorem` package with the options `amsmath` and `thmmarks` -- as in  `\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}` -- to enable the automatic placement of end-of-theorem marks (and to improve compatibility with amsmath)?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for that link, but I don't see a solution there. I'm loading `ntheorem` with options including these. If I use an unnumbered equation, then the QED symbol is placed fine, with and without an explicit `\qedhere`.

Comment: @eldering: Would you be able to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your current set up? Perhaps for a theorem with *and* without an ending equation.

Comment: @Werner: see MWE in edited answer below. Note that my question is about the `proof` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the following two suggestions:

1. Reword your proof. Even if you merely state the obvious:

   ```
   ...
           x^n + y^n = z^n
   which completes the proof.
   ```

   or

   ```
   Proof. It follows trivially that for
           x^n + y^n = z^n
   there exist no solutions.
   ```
2. Place the QED symbol manually next to the equation and correct for horizontal alignment with `\phantom` or use `\rlap`. Hopefully this is not something that has to be done frequently.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
   \usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,amsthm,hyperref]{ntheorem}

   \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
   \begin{document}

   \begin{proof}
     foo.
   \end{proof}

   \begin{proof}
     It follows trivially that no solutions exist for
     \begin{equation*}\label{eq:fermat1}
       x^n + y^n = z^n.
       \refstepcounter{equation}
       \tag*{(\theequation)}
     \end{equation*}
   \end{proof}

   \begin{proof}
     It follows trivially that no solutions exist for
     \begin{equation}\label{eq:fermat2}
       x^n + y^n = z^n. \rlap{$\qquad \Box$}
     \end{equation}
   \end{proof}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: You can use `\rlap{\qquad\qedsymbol}` instead of `\phantom` on the other side.

Comment: Thanks: this confirms my ideas for possible solutions. The `\rlap` placement of the QED symbol is neat.

Answer (score 1):

The following (somewhat dirty) solution seems to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,amsthm,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  foo.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
  It follows trivially that no solutions exist for
  \begin{equation*}\label{eq:fermat}
    x^n + y^n = z^n.
    \refstepcounter{equation}
    \tag*{(\theequation)}
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

It places the QED symbol right below the equation number, which is not as ugly as I had thought it would be.

I must acknowledge @egreg's comment, though, that it is not perfect from a stylistic point of view.

**Edit:** Now a full MWE, and I noticed that I had defined

```
\newcommand{\qedhere}{}
```

for backward compatibility with `amsmath` because `ntheorem` automatically places the QED symbol.

Comment: Please post fully compilable examples including `\documentclass` and all the packages required, as opposed to code snippets.