# I want to end a proof with a multiline equation

Tags: equations, numbering

This question is related to [placement of QED symbol on numbered equation line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33452/placement-of-qed-symbol-on-numbered-equation-line) but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

I want to end a proof with a multiline environment which is numbered (actually, an XYpic diagram) I would like the number to be center-aligned vertically, but the QED box to be at the bottom. I've tried a number of combinations of aligned and gathered with qedhere without particular success, but I feel sure it's possible.

**update**: an MWE has been requested. This one isn't quite minimal in that it includes the whole diagram, but the rest of the code is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-7pt/\dir{>}}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This follows from the commutativity of the bundle square
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}[b]
        \begin{aligned}
            \xymatrix@C=1em@R=1.5em{
                & G \ar[ddl]_j 
                    \ar[d]|{\varkappa \,\circ\, j}
                    \ar[ddr]\ar[drr]
                &
                \\
                & {}_KG_K 
                    \ar[rr]|(.24)\hole  
                    \ar'[d][dd] 
                &                       
                & BG \ar[dd]^\pi 
                \\
                  G_K \ar@{ >->}[ru]_\varkappa 
                    \ar[rr] 
                    \ar[dd]_\chi    
                &
                & EG \ar[ru] 
                    \ar[dd] 
                & 
                \\
                & BK \times BK  
                    \ar'[r]_(.675){\rho \times\rho}[rr]
                &
                & BG \times BG.
                \\
                  BK 
                    \ar@{ >->}[ru]_(.55){(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{pt})}         
                    \ar[rr]_\rho        
                &
                &
                  BG 
                    \ar@{ >->}[ru]_(.55){(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{pt})}
                &
            }
    \\[-\dp\strutbox]
    \end{aligned}
    \end{gathered}
    \qedhere
    \end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the equation number and QED box both align with `\pi`, whereas I'd like the number to align with `\pi` in the middle and the box to align with BG at the bottom.

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) of what you've done so far.

Comment: Would you end a proof with a one line numbered equation? Well, it's the same.

Comment: @egreg: the desire appears to be a number vertically centered (i.e. following the middle equation) and a box at the end of the bottom equation.

Comment: @JPi That's clear, my objection is that it wouldn't be nice.

Comment: egreg: For the record, I would not scruple to do exactly that if there were enough room for both the box and the equation number. In a format where equation numbers were left-aligned, I would think it entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the usual placement of the proof's qed symbol, but backup vertically just before:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-7pt/\dir{>}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This follows from the commutativity of the bundle square
\begin{equation}
  \vcenter{
    \xymatrix@C=1em@R=1.5em{
        & G \ar[ddl]_j
            \ar[d]|{\varkappa \,\circ\, j}
            \ar[ddr]\ar[drr]
        &
        \\
        & {}_KG_K
            \ar[rr]|(.24)\hole
            \ar'[d][dd]
        &
        & BG \ar[dd]^\pi
        \\
          G_K \ar@{ >->}[ru]_\varkappa
            \ar[rr]
            \ar[dd]_\chi
        &
        & EG \ar[ru]
            \ar[dd]
        &
        \\
        & BK \times BK
            \ar'[r]_(.675){\rho \times\rho}[rr]
        &
        & BG \times BG.
        \\
          BK
            \ar@{ >->}[ru]_(.55){(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{pt})}
            \ar[rr]_\rho
        &
        &
          BG
            \ar@{ >->}[ru]_(.55){(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{pt})}
        &
    }
  }
\end{equation}

\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}
\end{proof}

Following text.
\end{document}
```