# Remove the qed symbol from only one proof environment, not all

Tags: math-mode, symbols, theorems

I have seen several posts on how to remove the qed symbol in a proof, but that affects all proof environments. I would like to know how to remove the qed symbol in a particular proof because I have one proof inside another.

Comment: If you write `\phantom\qedhere` anywhere in the proof the qed symbol disappears. But I don't know if it's the best way of doing that.

Comment: Certainly, this works, but I have a proof in another, produces an excessive vertical space to the next paragraph.

Comment: That's why this is not optimal. You have to find where to put it with no problems manually. i.e., If you put it at the end of a paragraph, it works fine, but still manual. Wait until someone gives you an universal way of doing it.

Comment: If you need a block with *Proof* at the beginning why don't you fake it? 
For example `\par\noindent\textit{Proof.}\`.

Comment: Well, I found a way to do it but not very elegant. Thanks to Manuel, and all of you, for Replied. I added only
\vspace{-0.5cm}\phantom\qedhere after the inner proof.

Answer (score 49):

Just locally change the meaning of `\qedsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This has the QED symbol.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
This hasn't.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
And this has it again.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make a new environment for "inner proofs":

```
\newenvironment{innerproof}
 {\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}\proof}
 {\endproof}
```

which will do the same.

Comment: Thanks for response. This works, but produce extra vertical space for the next paragraph when it has a proof inside another. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JuanQuispe Some way or another you *have* to tell your reader when the inner proof ends

Comment: Yes. well, I found a way to do it, but is not very elegant. Merry Christmas

Comment: @JuanQuispe: Can you tell here? I think it would be interesting for other people also ...

Comment: I had the same issue with extra vertical space as @JuanQuispe and inserted `\renewcommand{\qed}{}` instead of `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` to get rid of the QED symbol. Not sure if this is a perfect solution but so far it seems to work. Also see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/end-of-theorem-marker-placement) for the details of the `\qedsymbol`, `\qed` etc. commands. (UPDATE: I just noticed that barbara beeton suggested the same solution in her answer below.)

Comment: @balu If you end your “no qed” proof with a display, you still need `\qedhere`.

Answer (score 34):

if you're using `amsthm`, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This has the QED symbol.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}\let\qed\relax
This hasn't.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
And this has it again.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

(thanks to egreg for providing an example that could be cribbed easily.)

Answer (score 7):

I handle such cases as follows.

```
\begin{proof}\phantom{\qedhere}
No QED symbol.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
QED symbol.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textellipsis
\item QED symbol at the end of the final item. \qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}\phantom{\qedhere}
\begin{equation}
\text{QED symbol at the end of the final equation.}\tag*{\qed}
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Comment: Not tested, but I suspect that if the last line of a proof finishes very close to the end of the line, `\phantom{\qedhere}` may result in an extra blank line.