# How can I temporarily change of end of a proof symbol which looks like $\square$ to $\triangle$?

Tags: symbols, renewcommand

I want to temporarily change the end of a proof symbol which looks like $\square$ to $\triangle$, a triangle symbol for a particular proof of a particular theorem, while for other theorems in the paper I still want to use $\square$ for the end of the proof.

Is it possible and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not simply use `QED` or, better, `όέδ`?

Answer (score 10):

I assume `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This ends with a square.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\triangle}}
This ends with a triangle.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I use `twocolumn` just to make a smaller picture.

[image]

You may want to define a new environment for this.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{varproof}
 {\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\triangle}}\proof}
 {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This ends with a square.
\end{proof}

\begin{varproof}
This ends with a triangle.
\end{varproof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [Remove the qed symbol from only one proof environment, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88164), Since the best answer there is yours, you might want to improve that by generalizing it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume `amsthm` is being used. Here is the ad-hoc solution addressing a single occurrence of a special theorem and its proof(s).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}

{
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}
\begin{theorem}[Special]
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Its proof.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
  Another one: \[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \qedhere \]
\end{proof}
}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]